# An assistant for REGEX editing

Tags: wysiwyg, regex

I am somewhat learned in using regex, but my coworkers aren't. I was wondering if there was some kind of WYSIWYG program out there that can assist people with making edits with regex. e.g. if somebody is trying to learn what regular expression they're supposed to use, they can highlight two sets of text in LibreOffice Writer or MSWord, and then this program I'm looking for will make some suggestions as to regex searches that fit both of the highlighted items.

FOSS is preferred, any operating system.

Comment: See [Free alternative to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132405/3416774) in SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would recommend the online [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python):

- Supported flavours: pcre (php), javascript & python
- Your own library and others
- Shows you what is going on as you construct your re
- Explains what each element does
- Built in quick reference
- Substitution Editor
- Code Generator
- re formatter for verbose options
- Free, gratis but contributions invited
- *Open Sourcing is under consideration at this time (2016).*
- Works on just about any internet connected device.

[image: example]

Doesn't suggest from a couple of examples: these would usually come down to `.+` without an expert system.

Comment: I use regex101 all the time, it has a nice library of different filtering options that come in handy a lot.